# Example for BASH two's complement with Hex values?

Tags: bash, hex, decimal, twos-complement

I have a routine that is collecting a hex value via SNMP. Here is a real collection from my bash script 08 01 18 00 FF FF. The value is base on expr $((16#${array[4]})) - $((16#${array[5]})) so the results are 0, how do I introduce two is complement? The correct value for expr $((16#${array[4]})) - $((16#${array[5]})) is -1 based on the example I am working on.

Comment: Can you explain why FF - FF should be -1?

Comment: `FF - FF` should be 0.

Comment: Unsigned value of 255 in twos complement is -1, how do you use twos complement in bash so if I had 255 how do I convert to -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, let's create a bash function:

```
twos() { x=$((16#$1)); [ "$x" -gt 127 ] && ((x=x-256)); echo "$x"; }
```

Now:

```
$ twos FF
-1
$ twos FE
-2
 $ twos 01
1
```

#### Converting multiple values in one call

Define an eXtended two's complement function:

```
$ twosx() { for x in "$@"; do x=$((16#$x)); [ "$x" -gt 127 ] && ((x=x-256)); printf "%s " "$x"; done; echo ""; }
```

Sample usage:

```
$ twosx 00 01 7F 80 FE FF
0 1 127 -128 -2 -1
```

Comment: is it possible to use echo for twosx() so I can combine the output with another string in the script like echo 'device 1=' twos & twosx 00 01 7F 80 FE FF

Comment: How about: `echo "device 1=$(twosx 00 01 7F 80 FE FF)"` ?