# Convert Twos complement results on one line rather than line by line, how?

Tags: bash, hex, twos-complement

I am using the code below to take values and convert them to two's complementary. I have tried twos FF & twos FE. How can I put it in a string so the results come back -1, -2 rather than line by line?

```
twos() { x=$((16#$1)); [ "$x" -gt 128 ] && ((x=x-256)); echo "$x"; }
```

Now:

```
$ twos FF
-1
$ twos FE
-2
 $ twos 01
1
```

Comment: What's missing in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31798763/1030675 ?

Comment: @choroba: The `,` character.

Comment: @MichaelJaros: It can be added to the `printf`, you then just have to remove the trailing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31798763/3030305) to add commas, let's create the function:

```
$ twosx() (c=; for x in "$@"; do x=$((16#$x)); [ "$x" -gt 127 ] && ((x=x-256)); printf "%s%s" "$c" "$x"; c=", "; done; echo ""; )
```

Examples of its use:

```
$ twosx 00
0
$ twosx 00 01 7F 80 FE FF
0, 1, 127, -128, -2, -1
```

Answer (score 0):

As @choroba has commented, there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31798763/1030675) providing (almost) the code you need already.

I am still answering this because the question actually consists of two problems, that is calculating two's complement and doing it multiple times. If you separate the two problems instead of duplicating code, you can also do other calculations multiple times in the same way:

```
# execute a command for each argument provided,
# concatenating output with ", " 
# $1 ....... command
# $2 - $n .. command arguments
multi() {
    cmd="$1"
    shift
    for arg in $@
    do
        "$cmd" "$arg"
    done | xargs | sed 's/ /, /g'
}
```

Usage:

```
multi twos FF FE AB 01
-1, -2, -85, 1
```